# Access-Control-Allow-Origin not appearing on headers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am searching for this problem for almost 3 hours.

So i am using codeigniter in developing my application.

So I am trying to make an AJAX request in this url 'login/loguser'

However, it is saying that there is No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://ssmis.wc.lt' is therefore not allowed access.

I know you will say I should put header() about access control origin. So I've done this

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class LogIn extends Ss_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        //So in case we have to do something in the constructor we dont override the parent constructor.
        parent::__construct();

    }

    function index(){
        $data['title'] = "Login";
        $data['page_content'] = "login_view.php";

        $extra_css = array(
            "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play",
            "public/system_css/login.css",
        );

        $data['extra_css'] = $extra_css;

        $extra_js = array(
            "public/system_js/modules/main.js",
            "public/system_js/login.js",
            "public/system_js/modules/login_module.js"
        );

        $data['extra_js'] = $extra_js;

        $this->load->view('includes/template.php',$data);
    }

    function loguser(){
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
        $data = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); // returns all POST items with XSS filter

        $this->load->model('usermod');

        $validated = $this->usermod->validate_credentials($data);

        //when $result returns true redirect to home page.
        if($validated){
            //set sessions cookies.
            $data = array(
                "username" => $data['batch_id'],
                "is_logged_in" => true
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            //redirect to home page.
            $response['success'] = true;
            $this->echo_response($response,200,'OK');   
        }else{
            //redirect to log-in page with error message
            $response['success'] = false;
            $this->echo_response($response,201,'Not OK!');  
        }
    }

}
```

This is my ajax code:

```
var login = function login(formdata){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: Main.Vars.host + 'login/loguser',
            contentType: false,
 headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
       crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,   
            processData:false, 
            data: formdata,
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(data){

                if(data.success == true){
                    window.location.assign(Main.Vars.host + "home/");
                }else{
                    alert("Cannot logged in!");
                }

            }

        });
    };
```

As you can see I already put Access-Control-Allow-Origin in my ajax call and in my controller class because i am so desperate right now.

I tried also putting header on my custom Base_Controller which looks like this:

This is my Base_Controller which extends CI_Controller

```
//echo response in json format.
    public function echo_response($data, $code, $status_message){
        $this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $this->output->set_header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
        $this->output->set_status_header($code, $status_message);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

I tried all the things that I've research, but still no luck. Access COntrol Allow Origin header still not present when performing the ajax call. I really need help.

PS i also tried jsonp in ajax but gives me error.

Thank you!

Comment: The header ***has*** to be present on the page you're getting with ajax, which in your case seems to be `http://ssmis.wc.lt`. Do you control that site and the headers it's sending, if not there's nothing you can do to make it work.

Comment: I am the one who write the back end sir. So I can put headers on those files. I dont know where exactly.

Comment: Anywhere before actual output is just fine

Comment: yes, I can see Acess Control Origin on first load, when loading my views and the default controller. The problem is on sending ajax to the url 'login/loguser'

Comment: If you want JSONP you'll need a wrapper, something like `echo "func(" . json_encode($data) . ");";`

Comment: can you please, ellaborate about jsonp?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78029/discussion-between-jc-frane-and-adeneo).

Comment: It's just JSON wrapped in a function, you either set a static function name or get it from `$_GET["callback"]` or something, and wrap the JSON with it.

Comment: you call with AJAX some API point or resource on your server - when composing the response you need to set the headers correctly.

Comment: my request header actually has access control allow origin header. My response has none. SO i think i dont have to use jsonp here.

Comment: It doesn't matter what your request has, it doesn't need CORS headers, the website responding is the one that has to allow CORS.

Comment: yeah, so technically, i should allow access control on backend right?